# discard (replace) bracket in javascript failed

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
str = "["1,2,3"]";
arr = str.replace('[','').replce(']','').split(',');
```

the result of 1 became, ""1"? How to convert above string into a proper array?

Answer (score 0):

**Errors** in your code:

1. `str` is not valid string. Use appropriate quote to nest or escape it by preceding `\`
2. Mispelled function name `replce` should be `replace`(missed `a`)
3. Use `match()` with `regex` to extract numbers from string.

```js
str = "['1,2,3']";
arr = str.match(/\d+/g);

document.write(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: is that an arr? why u didn't use push()?

Comment: @AliceXu Yes, you can see that in browser `console`

Comment: @AliceXu Because `match` returns the array of all matches

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is error in your first line it should be like either

```
str = "[\"1,2,3\"]";
```

or

```
str = '["1,2,3"]';
```

Simply you can do it with **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**, `\d+` match digit elements in the strings and returns array of matched elements.

```js
str = '["1,2,3"]';
console.log(str.match(/\d+/g));
```

Also you can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** and **[`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**

1. Replace `["` and `"]` in the string using `replace(/\["|"\]/g,'')`
2. Split the result string using `split(',')`

```js
str = '["1,2,3"]';
console.log(str.replace(/\["|"\]/g,'').split(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

First  you String has multiple quotes, correct it:

```
str = "[1,2,3]";
```

or

```
str = "["+"1,2,3"+"]";
```

Then use:

```
arr = str.replace('[','').replce(']','').split(',');
```

Now,
arr[0] will contain 1
arr[1] will contain 2
arr[2] will contain 3